# How to Handle OnResume for Multiple Fragments in stack with a single Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns, onresume, activity-lifecycle

I have a scenario where in a single Activity will have 5 fragments added(not replaced)upon each other to stack. When the Activity was resumed i noticed the OnResume of all the fragments getting called, which I think is as per the Lifecycle.

If I am handling any data or doing UI changes based on the data passed from previous fragment in the OnResume of any of my Fragments, those changes are also happening. Is there any design patten or any way to handle this particular case? That is when the Activity is resumed the OnResume of the fragments that are down the stack must not be called.

Comment: `If I am handling any data or doing UI changes based on the data passed from previous fragment in the OnResume of any of my Fragments they will also get initialized.` what will get initialized ??

Comment: @SantanuSur sorry my bad. I will edit the question. Actually i wanted to say ,
If I am handling any data or doing UI changes based on the data passed from previous fragment in the OnResume of any of my Fragments the UI changes that are done in the OnResume of the fragments that are in stack are also happening.

Comment: So when Activity loads, you also load ALL of your fragments at once? How are those fragments aligned? Like tab layout? Or are they all visible? How this activity look like?

Comment: @Variag No. I am adding one by one. Ex. Frag1- Home, frag2-Profile, frag3-details,then 4 and 5 similarly. They are in a frame layout. One over another. Added in backstack

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you could define `bool firstRun;` and set it to `true` in `onCreate()` of your activity. Then check it in activity's `onResume()`:

1. on first run it will be `true` so change it to `false`,
2. on resuming for second time it's `false`.

Then create getter in activity that will return your `firstRun` value and check it in fragments `onResume()`:

```
public onResume() {
   MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
   if (activity != null && activity.isFirstRun()) {
     // should execute only when activity starts for the first time
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could get it done by this way. But i think this is not a best practice. So I am looking for a better approach